# How to classify "unknown artist", "unknown album" in Itunes?

Tags: itunes, id3-tag

I have a cd with x mp3 files on it. After importing them to `iTunes` (Apple-O, Add to Library), songs appear on disk at

[image]

I can't seem to be able reference these files form `iTunes` in any form. Search for any of the songs reveal nothing.

How can i access these songs in `iTunes` to help me name them appropriately?

Answer (score 2):

You want to re-import those songs into your iTunes library. When viewing the songs, sort by the date added field. (You can add columns by right clicking any information header in the song list and adding check marks to the menu that shows).

Since the exact steps vary based on your OS and the version of iTunes, you can add that to your question or use iTunes help on importing songs from the computer folders and it will show you how to add those missing songs to the Library database that iTunes maintains.

Once you have an imported song, you can use iTunes to add titles and albums so that the storage on your filesystem is proper.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to edit information about your songs.

Comment: Actually, the OP can't even find the songs in iTunes. Could you edit your answer to provide recommendations on how to get to the songs so they can edit information?

Answer (score 1):

*Adding Operating System and iTunes version is beneficial, as well the kind of searching you already did.*

1. in iTunes, make a smart list (right-click the + button downleft)
2. make a rule like this: [date added] [is in the last] X [days]
3. click OK, and you'll find a smart list of most recently added numbers (if not, change 'X' to a bigger number).

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Media Monkey](http://www.techlife.net/2014/07/use-mediamonkey-to-achieve-music-library-management-zen.html)

It seemed to find tags/titles better than anything else I've used before.

Cheers